# How to display error messages when duplicate values are pushed into an array AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to do validation in my webpage. I want to prevent duplicate values entered when new users are added when filling up the form and submitting. Need to prevent duplicate values like same emil id, lastname or contact no. I want to display error message that they are already in use. Thanks in advance.

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("users") === null) {
  $scope.users = [{
      email: "Vai@yahoo.com",
      password: "Sha123",
      firstName: "Vai",
      lastName: "LSha",
      contact: "123-223-8989",
      role: "Super-Admin",
      company: ""
    },
    {
      email: "John@yahoo.com",
      password: "John123",
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe",
      contact: "281-283-2480",
      role: "Supplier-Admin",
      company: "Apple"
    },
    {
      email: "Ted@yahoo.com",
      password: "Ted123",
      firstName: "Ted",
      lastName: "Lucifer",
      contact: "123-223-2484",
      role: "Buyer-Admin",
      company: "Oneplus"
    }
  ];
  localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
} else {
  $scope.users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
}
$scope.companies = [];
var newCompany = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newCompany"));
$scope.companies = newCompany.map(item => item.name)

$scope.saveUser = function() {
  console.log("Saving...");
  $scope.users.push($scope.newUser);
  $scope.info = "New User Added Successfully!";
  $scope.newUser = {};
  localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
  $scope.addForm.$setPristine()
};
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table100-head">
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-if="showUser(user)" ng-repeat="user in users | filter: searchUsers track by $index">
      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
      <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{user.contact}}</td>
      <td>{{user.role}}</td>
      <td>{{user.company}}</td>
      <td>
        <button ng-disabled="checkRole()" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEdit" ng-click="selectUser(user)">Edit</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button ng-disabled="checkRole()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDelete" ng-click="selectUser(user)">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div>
  <form name="addForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addForm.addEmail.$invalid && !addForm.addEmail.$pristine }">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="addEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="newUser.email" ng-required="true">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="addForm.addEmail.$invalid && !addForm.addEmail.$pristine">
                                        Your Email is required.
                                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addForm.addPassword.$invalid && !addForm.addPassword.$pristine }">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="addPassword" placeholder="Enter New Password" ng-model="newUser.password" ng-required="true">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="addForm.addPassword.$invalid && !addForm.addPassword.$pristine">
                                        Your Password is required.
                                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addForm.addFirstName.$invalid && !addForm.addFirstName.$pristine }">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addFirstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" ng-model="newUser.firstName" ng-required="true">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="addForm.addFirstName.$invalid && !addForm.addFirstName.$pristine">
                                        Your First Name is required.
                                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addForm.addLastName.$invalid && !addForm.addLastName.$pristine }">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addLastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" ng-model="newUser.lastName" ng-required="true">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="addForm.addLastName.$invalid && !addForm.addLastName.$pristine">
                                        Your Last Name is required.
                                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Contact</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addForm.addContact.$invalid && !addForm.addContact.$pristine }">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="addContact" placeholder="Enter Contact" ng-model="newUser.contact" ng-required="true">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="addForm.addContact.$invalid && !addForm.addContact.$pristine">
                                        Your Contact is required.
                                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Role</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addForm.addRole.$invalid && !addForm.addRole.$pristine }">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addRole" placeholder="Enter Role" ng-model="newUser.role" ng-required="true">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="addForm.addRole.$invalid && !addForm.addRole.$pristine">
                                        Your Role is required.
                                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Company</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addForm.addCompany.$invalid && !addForm.addCompany.$pristine }">
        <select class="form-control" name="addCompany" placeholder="Select Company" ng-options="company for company in companies" ng-model="newUser.company" ng-required="true">
        </select>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="addForm.addCompany.$invalid && !addForm.addCompany.$pristine">
                                        Your Company is required.
                                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-hide="addForm.$invalid" ng-click="saveUser(); clearInfo()" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: We can’t rely on other people to do our work for us. If we try for ourselves, we may succeed.

Comment: I know. I'm just trying to do my best. I have my school project deadline by next week. Its just these validations which isn't working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need something like that, with some customization, of course:

```
$scope.saveUser = function() {
    console.log("Saving...");
    const isEmailDuplicated = !!$scope.users.find(user => $scope.newUser.email === user.email);
    const isNameDuplicated = !!$scope.users.find(user => $scope.newUser.lastName === user.lastName);
    const isContactDuplicated = !!$scope.users.find(user => $scope.newUser.contact === user.contact);
    if (isEmailDuplicated || isNameDuplicated || isContactDuplicated) {
        console.log("The user with such profile data already exists");
    } else {
        $scope.users.push($scope.newUser);
        console.log("New User Added Successfully!");
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Its totally working!.  Can you please explain me what's this "user =>"? And also why do you use two "!!" for "!!$scope.users.find"? I know these questions might sound silly, but I'm new to this. Thanks again man :)

Comment: Sure! Your questions aren't silly, it's just some 'shorthand' techniques, so you can use it or choose more habitual syntax. When I write `user => $scope.newUser.contact === user.contact` it's just a way to write `function(user) {return $scope.newUser.contact === user.contact}` called arrow function (you can google it). As for !! - it's a trick to make any input value boolean, in this case you just check if the result of `$scope.users.find(...)` function (which is user object) exists. If `find()` returns anything - it's transformed to `true`, if not - to `false`.